# Garbled index with ltxdoc document class

Tags: indexing, documentation, makeindex

When using the `ltxdoc` document class, index entries are misformatted, looking like this:

```
foomacro= \subitem *+\foomacro+, \usage{1}
```

rather than… however they’re supposed to look.

This sounds like a weird system-dependent thing, so here’s my distribution information:

- `ltxdoc.cls` at version `2018/03/15 v2.0x`
- `ltxbase` package (including `ltxdoc.cls`) packaged 2018-05-29
- Up-to-date packages as of 2018-10-25
- MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit
- Windows 10

---

## MWE

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\PageIndex
\begin{document}
\DescribeMacro{foomacro}
Some description here\dots
\PrintIndex
\end{document}
```

## Generated files

`bad-index.idx`:

```
\indexentry{foomacro=\verb!*+\foomacro+|usage}{1}
```

`bad-index.ilg`:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9.6800 64-bit] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file extra\bad-index.idx....done (1 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries...done (0 comparisons).
Generating output file extra\bad-index.ind....done (6 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in extra\bad-index.ind.
Transcript written in extra\bad-index.ilg.
```

`bad-index.ind`:

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item foomacro=\verb
    \subitem *+\foomacro+, \usage{1}

\end{theindex}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of garbled index]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With things like the doc-package or the ltxdoc-class you need to call the **makeindex**-program

- with the style-file **gind.ist** for creating the index,
- with the style-file **gglo.ist** for creating the change-history.

I.e., if the following is saved as **test.tex**:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\PageIndex
\begin{document}
\DescribeMacro{foomacro}
Some description here\dots
\PrintIndex
\end{document}
```

, then for creating the index you need to invoke **makeindex** as follows:

```
makeindex -s gind.ist -o test.ind test.idx
```

, and for creating the change-history you need to invoke **makeindex** as follows:

```
makeindex -s gglo.ist -o test.gls test.glo
```

So the entire command-sequence is something like:

```
pdflatex test.tex
makeindex -s gind.ist -o test.ind test.idx
makeindex -s gglo.ist -o test.gls test.glo
```

(Repeat this command-sequence until all references etc match out correctly
and the .log-file **test.log** does not contain warnings any more about the
need of running LaTeX again.)